# For best DB performance should I serialize all theme options together or by type?

Tags: theme-development, database, mysql, theme-options

If my theme has a lot of options is it better to store all options in one database entry, or to use a databse entry for each group of options? IE would I name all options like this `themeSlug[optionType_specificOption]` or like this: `themeSlug_optionType[specificOption]`?In the latter example if I need the settings for my post slider I would do `$sliderOptions = get_option('themeSlug_slider');`.

I guess my question is do I see any performance benefit to making several smaller queries vs  one large query for my options? Are their any other advantages/disadvantages to grouping my options into different entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All options with `autoload = yes` (default) are fetched very early in one query. So the number of options does affect performance only marginally.

Split options if you don’t need everything on every page load. With …

```
add_option( 'option_name', 'option_value', '', 'no' );
```

… you can set options that aren’t loaded before you actually call `get_option()`.

Comment: I didn't know you can do that. Can I do that when I am creating options via the theme customizer?

Comment: You have to call `add_option()` before you start the customizer code.